# Unit-test circular model references in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automapper

We are using AutoMapper and recently to our project we added `AutoMapper.Collection` (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) package (N-tier application, to help us paint the state of disconnected DB entities).

Everything works fine, but we noticed that if you have two models with circular references, e.g.:

```
public class Foo
{
   public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar 
{
   public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class FooDto
{
   public List<BarDto> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarDto
{
   public FooDto Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and you try to map from `Foo` to `FtoDto` or vice-versa, (without `.MaxDepth()` or `.PreserveReferences()` specified on the `CreateMap`) a `System.StackOverFlowException` is raised.

We know that circular references on `Dto` layer in most cases are a code smell, but we still want to protect ourselves from human errors or exception cases.

One idea we have is for AutoMapper to globally specify `MaxDepth`, at the same time, we have an idea of a different approach - through `System.Reflection` find all models with circular references and unit-test if in mapping profiles either way `MaxDepth` or `PreserveReferences` is specified.

There are 2 questions:

1. What's the most optimal way to find circular model references in an assembly through `System.Reflection`?
2. What would be the steps further to validate that these models contain `MaxDepth`/`PreserveReferences` in mapping profiles? Get all mappings registered and loop through comparing against the circular references list and check if `MaxDepth`/`PreserveReferences` is specified?

Comment: It should work by default without _any_ settings. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail. Without AM.Collection, just the base package.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I can confirm that with just base package it works as expected (by default). The issue occurs when we add AM.Collection.

Comment: You can investigate further and try to fix it yourself or sponsor someone to do it for you. Or maybe workaround it somehow.